Emergency mode journalctl shows fail mount
I have a pc with 3 disks:
- HDD1: /dev/sdb2 <-> mnt/disk1
- HDD2: /dev/sda2 <-> mnt/disk2
- SSD2: /dev/nvme0n1p2 <-> mnt/ssd2

The ssd is the one containing the homes.
On boot I get the You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb..."
If I run that and check the output, I can see:
systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/disk1

there are other failures, such as:
nvme1n1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme1n1' failed with exit code 1
nvme0n1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1' failed with exit code 1
sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1
sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1
nvme1n1p2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme1n1p2' failed with exit code 1
nvme0n1p1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p1' failed with exit code 1

Any ideas?

My /etc/fstab looks like this:
UUID=... / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=... /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb2 mnt/disk1 ext4 defaults 0 0

should I comment out the last line, reboot and hope for the best?

The last line in your fstab should probably be /dev/sdb2 /mnt/disk1 ext4 defaults 0 0 ... that is, with a / in front of mnt.

@SorenA did that and nothing changed.. do you need the whole log?

I just commented out the line in /etc/fstab regarding the disk which mount was failing and it worked

How did you get the system to boot up such that you could comment out that one line?  Edit: you just hit Q to leave the journalctl output and then you have access to vi into /etc/fstab as normal.

@AustinHeller i genuinely don’t recall... hope you managed to fix it, sorry
